# RestClient syntax for file uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-api-v1

Following the [indications provided by this gem](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#multipart) , testing in the Rails console the RestClient

```
RestClient.post "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image", :myfile => File.new("/Users/main/Desktop/ss2022-11-03_11.39.11.png", 'rb')
```

one can assert that the file exists by changing its path.  Once verified, the response returns
 `400 Bad Request`.  So the request is malformed.  Alas, I do not grasp what the second element of the `File.new` represents

The version 1.1 API documentation provides a suggestion console test

```
twurl -X POST -H upload.twitter.com "/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=TWEET_IMAGE&additional_owners=3805104374" -f adsapi-heirarchy.png -F media
```

the response is the same whether the `additional_owners` is included or not (logical, it is optional).

What is missing in this sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Thr translation of the twurl syntax to curl syntax would be:

```
curl "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image&additional_owners=3805104374" --data-urlencode @/Users/main/Desktop/adsapi-heirarchy.png --data-urlencode 'media'
```